# pebble time color configuration

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I try to optimize my configuration of my pebble time watchface. To avoid string comparisons I put all GColor values into an array, but it doesn't work at all :(

The array:

```
static uint8_t colors[] = {
GColorInchwormARGB8,    //1
GColorSpringBudARGB8,    //2
GColorBrightGreenARGB8,    //3
GColorMintGreenARGB8,    //4
GColorScreaminGreenARGB8,    //5
GColorGreenARGB8,    //6
GColorMalachiteARGB8,    //7
};
```

read the data from the config:

```
static void in_recv_handler(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context)
{

  Tuple *t = dict_read_first(iterator);

  while (t != NULL){
    switch (t -> key){
      //++++++ background color +++++++
      case bgColor:
       persist_write_int(bgColor, t->value->int8);
      break;
      //++++++ time color ++++++
      case timeColor:
        persist_write_int(timeColor, t->value->int8);
      break;
    } 
     t = dict_read_next(iterator);
  } 
}
```

I tried uint8, uint16, uint32, int8, int16 and int32. If I use int32 the watch crash.

Set the color to the layer:

```
time_color = (GColor)colors[persist_read_int(timeColor)];
```

When I use:

```
time_color = (GColor)colors[4];
```

the right color appears.

the values of the html page:

```
 <select id="bg_select">
          <option class="inchworm" value="0">Inchworm</option>
          <option class="springBud" value="1">Spring Bud</option>
          <option class="brightGreen" value="2">Bright Green</option>
          <option class="mintGreen" value="3">Mint Green</option>
    </select>
```

Does anybody have suggestions to fix it? What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact order of events, the color value might not have been saved yet. Are you checking for whether the value exists?

```
if(persist_exists(timeColor)) {
  time_color = (GColor)colors[persist_read_int(timeColor)];
}
```

Comment: This might be it... the docs say that you should check existence before reading.  Also writes can fail so you should check the return code when writing.